# type-safe calculation of off_t offset for ftruncate() in C

Tags: c, types

Having parsed the logs of a job to know from where to restart it, I may find some corruption at the end (eg if the system crashed); in that case I want to truncate the bad data before continuing.

I'm currently opening the file with `fopen(path, "a+");`, and have read a line with `nread = getline(&buf, &len, fp);`. If I detect corruption I now want to truncate it with something like `ftruncate(fileno(fp), ftell(fp) - nread)` - but `ftell()` returns a `long`, `getline()` returns a `ssize_t`, and `ftruncate()` wants an `off_t`. So what is a correct, type-safe way to calculate the offset?

(And yes, I know that I also need to handle the state of the `FILE *` around the `ftruncate()` call, that will be my next problem.)

Comment: On a 64 bit system, a `long` is [probably] 64 bits (POSIX systems that are `LP64`). So, the `long` is _unlikely_ to ever be negative (i.e. greater than 4.6e18). So, no worries. Likewise, `ssize_t` is 64 bits, and so will be `off_t`. `off_t` _will_ be 64 bits even on a 32 bit system with `#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE` (or other similar define). If you're worried, you could use `fgetpos` instead of `ftell`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of `fgetpos` - but that seems to just shift the problem, by giving me yet another type `fpos_t`. Maybe I should be asking "where can I look up the invariants guaranteed for the various types?"

Comment: Your only real issue is that you might have a logfile that is > 2GB (i.e. > (1u << 31)) and a 32 bit number would overflow and go negative. On a 64 bit, this is a non-issue. On a 32 bit machine, `long` will be 32 bit (hence, `fgetpos` because `fpos_t` uses `off_t` internally). With the `#define`, `off_t` will be 64 bits--problem solved. Actually, what you want is `ftello` [which I just found myself ;-)]. It returns `off_t` instead of `long` which solves the issue directly. See `man ftello` for details re. `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ftello`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftello.html) instead of `ftell`. It's identical except for returning an `off_t` rather than a `long`. This avoids the problem that the value that `ftell` should return might overflow `long`, before any operations even happen. This is a real problem on 32-bit systems that support files larger than 2GB.

`ftello` is POSIX, so it should be available on any system where `ftruncate` and other file descriptor functions are available except truly antique ones.

The arithmetic is in fact not an issue. The operands will be promoted to a type that can accommodate both operands' value. That in itself doesn't guarantee that the result will fit, but you know that `ftello(np)` is non-negative and `nread` is non-negative and less than `ftello(np)`, so the result is between 0 and `ftello(np)` and thus can fit in any type where `ftello(np)` fits.

Note that `ftello`, like `ftell`, returns -1 on error. Make sure to handle that case.

```
while (!end_of_file) {
    ssize_t nread = getline(fp, ...);
    if (nread == -1) goto error;
    off_t offset = ftello(fp);
    if (offset == -1) goto error;
    if (!valid_record(...)) {
        ftruncate(fp, offset - nread);
        ...
    }
}
```

But actually, I think it would make more sense to remember the last known-good offset, and truncate to that point if needed.

```
while (!end_of_file) {
    off_t good_offset = ftello(fp);
    if (good_offset == -1) goto error;
    ssize_t nread = getline(fp, ...);
    if (nread == -1) goto error;
    if (!valid_record(...)) {
        ftruncate(fp, good_offset);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `ftello()` is exactly what I needed; that `nread` is guaranteed to be small enough is also a good point. Given that my type-safety concern is satisfied, it makes sense to me to call `ftello()` once in the failure case rather than millions of times for every successful case.